SSL not trusted with cert-manager
I have an Azure K8S cluster with cert-manager installed.
I issued Lets encrypt SSL certificate for all my ingress with cert-manager http01 protocol with no error. SSL are correctly installed, renew is ok and browsers don't complain on it.
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: "email@gmail.com"
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: cert-manager-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: gateway
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tools-files
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: gateway
  rules:
    - host: api.foo.fr
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /v1/webhooks/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: tools
                port:
                  number: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.foo.fr
      secretName: api.foo.fr

But if I test it on SSLChecker.com, I have a warning in the Vendor Signed section with a "SSL not trusted" error message. How can I resolve this?

What does kubectl get secret api.foo.fr -n default -o yaml show? It should contain the entire certificate chain, including the intermediate certificates
